# How to flush buffer when ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator bufferSizeLimit exceeded?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, concurrency, spring-websocket

I'm using Spring Websocket in my project, I found that ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator stopped when bufferSizeLimit exceeded, but there is no method to recover it.

I use it in this way:

```
try {
    if (concurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.isOpen()) {
        concurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sendMessage(message);
    }
} catch (SessionLimitExceededException se) {
    logger.warn("sendMessage exceed limit: ", se);
    // TODO flush buffer
} catch (IOException ie) {
    logger.error("sendMessage failed: ", ie);
}
```

I read the code of concurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator, the method ***checkSessionLimits*** set ***limitExceeded=true*** and throws a SessionLimitExceededException when buffer size exceeded, but I cant't find any method which set ***limitExceeded=false***. How can I flush buffer and reset the limitExceeded?

```
public void sendMessage(WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws IOException {
    if (shouldNotSend()) {
        return;
    }

    this.buffer.add(message);
    this.bufferSize.addAndGet(message.getPayloadLength());

    do {
        if (!tryFlushMessageBuffer()) {
            if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                String text = String.format("Another send already in progress: " +
                        "session id '%s':, \"in-progress\" send time %d (ms), buffer size %d bytes",
                        getId(), getTimeSinceSendStarted(), getBufferSize());
                logger.trace(text);
            }
            checkSessionLimits();
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!this.buffer.isEmpty() && !shouldNotSend());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It flushes by itself in the already ran `tryFlushMessageBuffer()`:

```
private boolean tryFlushMessageBuffer() throws IOException {
    if (this.flushLock.tryLock()) {
        try {
            while (true) {
                WebSocketMessage<?> message = this.buffer.poll();
                if (message == null || shouldNotSend()) {
                    break;
                }
                this.bufferSize.addAndGet(message.getPayloadLength() * -1);
                this.sendStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                getDelegate().sendMessage(message);
                this.sendStartTime = 0;
            }
        }
        finally {
            this.sendStartTime = 0;
            this.flushLock.unlock();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

By I see your point about `limitExceeded` flag: we just don't go to that `tryFlushMessageBuffer()` because we already exist just after `shouldNotSend()`. And that's because you are right that `limitExceeded` is never reseted.

Sounds really like a bug. Please, raise a JIRA on the matter: https://jira.spring.io/projects/SPR

Comment: For info: the relevant ticket is https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21677 and has been addressed in Spring 5.1